# Flutter commands is not workimg

Tags: terminal, dart, flutter

when I run flutter command as a root user it did not run but it show something like an error

```
 Woah! You appear to be trying to run flutter as root.
We strongly recommend running the flutter tool without superuser privileges.
/

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
Dart_NewStringFromUTF8 expects argument 'str' to be valid UTF-8.
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong .Kindly help me.

I am trying to run flutter in Kali Linux with android studio installed.
Did I need to run flutter as a non-root user, if yes then I need to install everything for another user . is there any way to do this?

Comment: Running apps as root on Linux is strongly discouraged in general, so it might be a good idea to change that.

Comment: but i run every thing in root

Comment: I got that, but it's a bad idea. I hope you're not using Linux for security reasons :D

Comment: then I need to run flutter as a non-root user ,is  this  what I need to do

Comment: You should run everything as non-root user expect some specific admin tasks like changing some config or install apps that need to be installed as root. Otherwise just don't use root. I don't know a short-term workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have installed the android studio in your root account.
there is no other option for you.
you have to give a non-root user the permission to use it.
you cant log in the shell alone also.
I recommend you to install only flutter there and use in some text editor an shell commands that's better than as.
kali has some different rules than normal Linux repos.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter doctor`

and do as it suggest

Comment: this is what happen when i run flutter device

Comment: flutter devices
   Woah! You appear to be trying to run flutter as root.
   We strongly recommend running the flutter tool without superuser privileges.
  /

Dart_NewStringFromUTF8 expects argument 'str' to be valid UTF-8.